# Google Business API - only receive the original review without translation

Tags: google-my-business-api

I am using the API to receive reviews. The content of the reviews includes the original and a translated text:

```
Tolles Team (Translated by Google) great team
```

Is there a way to remove the translated version? Google changes the output of the content and we recieved different contents so far

```
(Translated by Google) ... (Original) ...
... (Translated by Google) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not, you will have to strip them out programmatically.